# How can I change the size and color of the holographic weapon sight?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm talking about [Aug's and SG553's sight](https://gamebanana.com/wips/45701) below, NOT the default crosshair. Right now, it's yellow and too small. I want to make it red and way bigger. I know nothing on programming or Comp Sci.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that, or at least, if you can, it's most likely gonna be something Valve really doesn't like you to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cl_crosshaircolor_b, cl_crosshaircolor_r, cl_crosshaircolor_g to determine the RGB colours of the crosshair, however, it is not currently possible to change the size of the sight crosshair

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzBPEWoxqhU) video, as it provides all information needed to do this.